# I have imported a project in android studio and have a "could not find android method" error

Tags: java, android

**Here's the build.gradle file**

```
   // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

    android {
        buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    }
    dependencies {
    }
```

**Here is the app build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resValue "string", "google_maps_key", (project.findProperty("GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY") ?: "")
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

The error is 
Error:(22, 0) Could not find method android() for arguments [build_4zgce4e0vr1il6017s3d6qypf$_run_closure3@4c674a56] on root project 'CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
Open File

How do I change this ,I have tried changing the build version too but it is not helping

Comment: can you show the app buil.gradle

Comment: Is it the full log ?

Comment: yes this is the full log